# Particleground и Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Когда начинаю использовать роутинг из Angular 1.6.9 перестает работать Particleground, как можно пофиксить ? 
Для прелоадера у меня используется Particleground, который перестает работать когда я использую это -

Для прелоадера у меня используется Particleground, который перестает работать когда я использую это -

```
 angular.module('myApp', [
 'ngRoute',
 'angular-page-loader'
 ]);
 angular.module('myApp')

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider

// main route
.when('/', {
    title: 'Homepage',
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    resolve: {
        timing: function($timeout, $q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                defer.resolve();
            }, 3000);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
})
    .when('/elements', {
    title: 'elements',
    templateUrl: 'pages/elements.html',
    resolve: {
        timing: function($timeout, $q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                defer.resolve();
            }, 3000);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
})
        .when('/generic', {
    title: 'generic',
    templateUrl: 'pages/generic.html',
    resolve: {
        timing: function($timeout, $q) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                defer.resolve();
            }, 3000);
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
})
// sample route
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

Comment: конкретизируйте и покажите код

Comment: `particleground` этот? https://github.com/jnicol/particleground

Comment: Да, этот particleground

Comment: у вас он вообще не работает или работает на 1 странице, а потом после навигации перестает?

Comment: Он работал да того как я добавил ngRoute

Comment: консоль пишет что-то?

Comment: index.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Comment: я понял, дайте 5 минут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходит по той причине, что вы вызываете данный метод, когда `angular-route` еще не отрендерил шаблон, поэтому при начальной загрузке приложения вешаем обработчик событий `DOMContentLoaded` на `document` и вызываем `particleGround` и точно также вешаем слушатель на событие успешной навигации и отрисовки шаблона.

```
const app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-page-loader']);

app.config( .....ваши роуты );

app.run(['$rootScope', ($rootScope) => {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', () => {
        const particleElement = document.querySelector('#your-element');

        if (!particleElement) {
            return;
        }

        particleground(particleElement, {
            dotColor: '#ff0000',
            lineColor: '#ff0000'
        });

        // или

        $(particleElement).particleground({
            dotColor: '#ff0000',
            lineColor: '#ff0000'
        });
    });
}]);

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
    const particleElement = document.querySelector('#your-element');

    if (!particleElement) {
        return;
    }

    particleground(particleElement, {
        dotColor: '#ff0000',
        lineColor: '#ff0000'
    });

    // или

    $(particleElement).particleground({
        dotColor: '#ff0000',
        lineColor: '#ff0000'
    });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: particleGround is not defined
    at angular.element.ready ((index):170)
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3488)

Comment: используйте значит вариант с `jquery` :-)

Comment: все равно не работает (          - (index):170 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).particleground is not a function
    at angular.element.ready ((index):170)
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.js:3488)

Comment: у вас эта библиотека не подключена :-)

Comment: Да, я заметил ), но все равно ошибки  http://i.prntscr.com/6-9wNhYzRvCklWPgn5vFoA.png

Comment: я исправил на `particleground` без `uppercase`

Comment: но все равно есть insertBefore

Comment: эта ошибка не может возникать по той причине, что стоит проверка на `null` и происходит преждевременный выход из функции если `true`, у вас точно файл обновился? возможно кеш или еще что-то, что у вас на 10 строчке `index.js`?

Comment: Все обновилось, кеш чистил

Comment: сделайте просто скрин кода `index.js`, так будет легче понять, где возникает ошибка, потому что мы пальцем в небо тыкаем

Comment: Извините, мой косяк, я исправил ту ошибку, но все равно не видно фона, это может быть связано с z-index ?

Comment: ошибка не возникает больше? просто создайте тестовый `div id="my-test-div"`, поставьте ему `width: 500px, height: 500px, background: green` и проверьте

Comment: Да все работает, только в моем прелоадере нет, спасибо, пойду дальше его ковырять )

Comment: если ответ вам действительно помог - пометьте его как лучший. cheers :-)